# Scatter polar plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to do a wedge plot (right ascension vs redshift). I was thinking I could use a scatter plot in polar coordinates. The polar function in matlab seems very limited. Even this

```
polar(a(:,1),a(:,2),'Linewidth',1)
```

gives me an error:

```
Error using polar (line 23)
Too many input arguments.
```

Is there a simple way to achieve what I want using Matlab? Do you know of another software that would do it easily?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Matlab is quite adequate for that, I think.

As for the `polar` function,  it seems it doesn't allow properties (such as `'linewidth'`) to be specified directly. But you can get a handle to the created object and then set its `'linewidth'`, or other properties:

```
h = polar(a(:,1),a(:,2));
set(h,'linewidth',1)
```

If you want a scatter plot, maybe you'd prefer not to have lines, but instead to plot a marker (such as a dot) at each point:

```
h = polar(a(:,1),a(:,2),'.');
set(h,'markersize',12)
```

Example:

[image]

To see a list of properties that you can set, as well as their current values, type

```
get(h)
```

Comment: Great stuff. To make it look more like a scatter plot, instead of point specifier '.' I use circle specifier 'o', and then set its properties with something like `set(h,'markersize',4, 'MarkerFaceColor','b');`