# Setting theta-ticks in matplotlib polar plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

My question is related to the following:
[Scatter polar plot in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317481/scatter-polar-plot-in-matlab)

I tried looking online but couldn't find any with this axis; instead of the polar plot going 0 to 360 degrees how can I do -180 to 180 instead?

Comment: The data between -180 and 0 will be displayed between 180 and 360, if you can live with the labels being 0-360

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After creating the polar axis, you can simply set the ticks. Note that you have to set the ticks in radians and matplotlib will display in degrees.

Not quite sure how you want to deal the discrepancy at 180 and -180.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))
ax1.set_xticks(np.pi/180. * np.linspace(180,  -180, 8, endpoint=False))
```

[image: polar axis]

Comment: Should the xticks be in any specific order? When I try to set arbitrary xticks (not using linspace), it displays only a segment instead of the whole polar disk.

Comment: @rudolfbyker look into the distinction between `xticks` and `xtick_labels`. it also sounds like you might want to write a custom `Locator` or `Formatter`

Comment: Nope, I figured it out. In newer `matplotlib` versions (since some time in 2017), setting `xticks` on a polar plot also influences the limits of theta. See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/4699 . Calling `ax.set_thetalim(-np.pi, np.pi)` after `ax.set_xticks(...)` ensures that the full circle is plotted. See https://matplotlib.org/api/projections_api.html#matplotlib.projections.polar.PolarAxes.set_thetalim .